# Magento 2 - How to call custom attribute saved in a phtml file and display it?

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I want to display some text after product price. For example $35 per kg. this text "per kg" I want to append on some products which I am selling on kg basis.

I have created a custom attribute with textfield. I have inserted value per kg into that attribute and assigned with the product I want it to be displayed.

Now my problem is I am not getting any way to call this custom attribute to append to price on frontend. I want this text to be displayed on both category and display page.

I am trying to edit:
`vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\base\templates\product\price\amount`

I can display custom text by echo but not getting any way to call that custom attribute. code of custom attribute is per kg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    $_tempid = $block->getPriceId();
    $_tempid1 = substr($_tempid, strrpos($_tempid, '-') + 1);
    $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_tempid1);
    $attr = $_product->getData('priceperkg');
if($attr == 1) {
    echo __('per kg');
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Don't edit the files in `vendor`. These will be overwritten when you do `bin/magento setup:upgrade`. It's a better practise to put your custom theme in `app/design/frontend/`.
Check Magento's guide: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

About your attribute, in stead of a text-field you could use a 'yes/no' input type. It will output 1 or 0.

You can get an attribute with:

```
$_product->getData('attribute_label')
```

So in your .phtml file you could do something like this:

```
$attr = $_product->getData('price_per_kg');

if($attr == 1) {
    echo __('Price per kg');
};
```